# Count keys within array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hi I want to return all the collections that have arrays count lesser than 2 inside `features` array in mongodb. I tried using `$size` but it is not possible.

I don't want to get the result and loop each of the `features` and count it. I want to return the `productId 123` because it has a count of 1 in one of features array. Please take below document as an example:

```
{
    "productId" : 123.0,
    "features" : [ 
        {
            "a" : true
        }, 
        {
            "a" : true,
            "b" : true
        }
    ]
},
{
    "productId" : 456.0,
    "features" : [ 
        {
            "a" : true,
            "b" : true
        }, 
        {
            "a" : true,
            "b" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are actually asking for is matching on the "count of the number of keys" within the array elements. You have different approaches to this depending on the available MongoDB version.

**MongoDB 3.4.4 and upwards**

You can use [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to coerce each element into an "array" itself, representing the "key/value" pairs of the elements:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$anyElementTrue": { 
          "$map": {
            "input": "$features",
            "as": "f",
            "in": {
              "$lt": [
                { "$size": { "$objectToArray": "$$f" } },
                2
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

You basically feed the condition with [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) which determines that for the results of [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) where the [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) is applied to each element and then tested for the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/size/), where any of the tested array elements returned `true` via [`$anyElementTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/).

**All Other Versions**

Anywhere else, looking somewhat more brief but actually not as performance effective is using [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) to apply a JavaScript expression to test the array elements. Same principle though using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
db.collection.find({
  "$where": function() {
    return this.features.some(f => Object.keys(f).length < 2 )
  }
})
```

Same deal but since the JavaScript requires interpretation and evaluation against every document, it actually runs quite a bit slower that the aggregation expression given.

Both return the same document, which is the one which has an element with "less than two keys" in the inner object, just as asked:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "productId" : 123.0,
    "features" : [ 
        {
            "a" : true
        }, 
        {
            "a" : true,
            "b" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I can't get it working since my version of MongodDb is 2.6.12. I tried the JavaScript but it has an error pertaining to the symbol `>`

Comment: @KristCont If your "shell" is really ancient then it does not understand ES6 syntax. There is nothing wrong with using a more modern shell with older "server" releases. But you can also change the `$where` argument to `return this.features.some(function(f)  { return Object.keys(f).length < 2 })`

Comment: I tried what you said on your comment above this but it returns error  ` Object.keys called on non-object near 'ys(f).length < 2 }` .

Comment: @KristCont Not from the data you presented in the question. The only way you get an error like that that is where your actual data structure does not resemble what was posted in the question. My answer is run on the data presented. Copied and pasted into a collection and the results copied and pasted into the answer. I suggest you do the same. If you cannot work out how to apply to "data that is different" to what you actually asked about, then you [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). But what you asked, has been answered.